# How can I post/deserialize unknown json object in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, json

I'm using MVC4.

Some code (that I can't get into here) is generating the form on the fly, so I have absolutely no idea what fields are posted back to my MVC controller.

Here's my Java:

```
var formData = $("#MyForm").serialize();
$.post('/mycontroler/postdata', formData, function (data) {
});
```

My problem is, how do I read this in MVC?

If I use...

```
Public Function postdata(data As String) As JsonResult
End Function
```

... the "data" variable is nothing.

So how do I read the querystring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your postdata function as such:

```
public function postdata(FormCollection collection) as JsonResult
```

then iterate over the fields and retrieve value(s)

```
foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
   {
      var value = formCollection[key];
      // etc.
   }

   foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
   {
       var value = formCollection[key.ToString()];
       // etc.
   }
```